# About molecular add-on in Mac

Tags: particles, add-on, osx

Im making some simulation in blender and get interested in molecular add-on. but it is not working in my computer. I'm using Mac Pro(10.13.2). And the blender version is 2.79. Someones says that add-on's version dosen't be a matter even if the blender is 2.79. But I couldn't find any information  about to add the add-on to Mac. I mean that I tried few times as Win's way but I failed.
 The add-on is downloaded on this website.(http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)

If you have any information about it, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to copy only the folder "addons" and the folder "molecular", if you try to copy both files that are in the folder "molecular" you can't install the addon.

Comment: Don't forget that Macs tend to decompress zipped files upon download. You may need to recompress the folders